# Atom can't spawn Flake8 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, flake8

I'm getting an error when I try to use Atom on Windows 10 with the linter-flake8 package:

```
Error: spawn flake8 ENOENT
    at getENOENTError (C:\Users\ME\.atom\packages\linter-flake8\node_modules\sb-exec\lib\helpers.js:159:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ME\.atom\packages\linter-flake8\node_modules\sb-exec\lib\index.js:50:46)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:493:12)
```

I'm assuming that this is because I've used WSL to set up what is basically a copy of my Ubuntu Python development environment - pyenv, virtualenv, git, and that I install flake8 within virtualenvs because I work with different Python versions.

I normally start Atom from within a project's virtualenv, but since I have to start Atom from outside Bash on Windows, I don't think its aware of the flake8 that I've got installed.

Am I right? My first idea for a solution is to just install flake8 system-wide and then get linter-flake8 to point to it, but that seems like a cumbersome way to do it. How should I work around this?

Comment: You're correct that Atom can't find the Flake8 executable. I believe linter-flake8 allows you to specify a path to the python executable though which they should use to do `python -m flake8`.

Comment: I checked, it just has an option to specify a path to flake8, and not to python.

Comment: I think it is duplicate of this question: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654434/atom-linter-flake8-failed-to-spawn-not-in-path/51196091#51196091>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for linter-flake8, it appears you can set the [`executablePath`](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8/blob/530fb4ebdc30d58310746780315dc4dec4b9f6a0/lib/main.js#L117).

This would require configuring it each time you start-up though.