# Atom linter-flake8 failed to spawn (not in PATH)

Tags: python, path, atom-editor, flake8, linter

i installed linter-flake8 package in Atom . I got this error :

> [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: Failed to spawn command `flake8`. Make sure `flake8` is installed and on your PATH

i'm sure flake8 is in the PATH . Have a look at the image i attach. I try to input the executable path to the flake8 setting but still doesn't work. I use windows 10 and i have python 2.7 and 3.5 installed . The 2.7 is installed in C:/python27, while 35 is installed in user/local folder (see attachment).

Found similar case in this forum , but still can't make it work. Does anyone know the solution ?

error message:
[image: error message]

confirm flake8 installed in both python version :
[image]

[image]

Tried to add path , but none of them works :
[image]

[image]

my env path has included the python lib (at the bottom) :
[image]

Comment: From the github status of `linter` the build fails for now. I think that might be one of the reason as linter-flake8 needs linter as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where is executable of flake8 on your system.
As you have Windows you need in CMD execute such command:

```
where flake8
```

and then resulting path add to PATH variable.
In my case that was

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

It means flake8 dir cannot be found by Atom.

The easiest way is to figure out where flake8 is located:

```
% which flake8
/Users/{username}/.pyenv/shims/flake8
```

Then go to Atom -> Preferences (MacOS) -> flake8 -> settings

[image: On flake8 Executable Path, add the path]
Post the path in the Executable Path box

And you're good to go!!